# How to increment a list in python containing both numbers and characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a list as [1,2,3,a,b,M] and need to increment every variable by 1 .

I have tried for number I can use as :

```
a = [1,2,3]
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i] += 1
print a
```

Also for characters I can use :

```
ch = 'M'
x = chr(ord(ch) + 1)
print ("The incremented character value is : ")
print (x)
```

But together I am not able to club it. Is there anyway by which i can club it?

Comment: Do you mean combine?

Comment: Are the numbers guaranteed to be single digit integers?

Comment: they can be either single digit or double digit..

Comment: Why is this tagged both [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x]? If you need a solution which is portable to Python 2 you should be more explicit about this requirement; and if not, please refrain from tag spam.

Answer (score 3):

You could try a list comprehension

```
[e+1 if isinstance(e,int) else chr(ord(e) + 1) for e in [1,2,3,'a','b','M']]
```

Comment: No `type` equality checks please... use `isinstance` instead, it's just better code hygiene.